# Exploding by a word

Tags: php, explode

I have a titles such as `The Oak Tree` or `The Pine`

I set up `$stylename = explode("The", $row->title);`

This should explode the phrase into

`$stylename[0] = 'The';`
`$stylename[1] = 'Oak Tree';`

But instead `$stylename[0]` is empty.

How can I alter the above code to export what I require?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to split on whitespace instead.

Comment: Explode eliminates the item used as delimiter that's why `The` is not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**preg_split**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
// split on the spaces which has `The` in front of it.
$stylename = preg_split('/(?<=The)\s+/', $row->title);
```

Answer (score 3):

Explode splits at the string you give it, so you have "" (nothing) then "The" (which was what it split at) then (the rest of it), more simply "abc" when you explode with b yields the two strings "a" and "c".

Use preg_split with a trivial regex instead, or artificially add the "the" back in, Regex is better as you can make it case insensitive, which you probably want ("the" in titles should have a lower case "t")

Answer (score 0):

`explode(" ", $row->title, 1)` should do it the way you want.

1 is the limit of how many times the given string should be splitted.

See http://php.net/explode

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$stylename = explode(" ", "The Oak tree");
$result[0] = $stylename[0];
unset($stylename[0]);
$result[1] = implode(" ",$stylename);
unset($stylename);
```

see demo [here](https://eval.in/108086)

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
$stylename = explode(" ", trim($row->title),1);
```

This should work